# Looking for a specific transition for Adobe Premiere

Tags: premiere, after-effects, adobe

Is it possible (and if yes, how) to create a transition using either Adobe Premiere or After Effects (and maybe import to Premiere then?) which zooms out of the first video displaying multiple videos next to each other (both vertical and horizontal) - like many tiles - and then it should zoom in to the next video. So I am looking for a transition where e.g. 30 videos are displayed (like a gallery) and it's zooming in to the next video until it's size is 100%. I've seen this transition a couple of times already (don't exactly know where) but I just don't know how it's called so I didn't find anything on the internet :/

Edit: not all videos have to be different every time, it's okay if all videos are fixed and only two are dynamic.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

This may get down-votes since it's so manual and doesn't have perfect video quality, but I'll offer it anyway.

**CREATING THE GENERIC TRANSITION**

1. Bring 30 clips into a project.
2. Shrink the scale of all of them.
3. Drag them onto the timeline so they're all playing at the same time.
4. Position them in a grid.
5. Export that project in the best possible quality you can.

**CREATING THE SPECIFIC TRANSITION**

1. Open the generic transition video in a new project. Place it on the timeline.
2. Bring in the 2 videos you want to transition between.
3. Shrink their scales, put them on the timeline, and position them over 2 of the existing videos.
4. Export that project in the best possibly quality (matching the generic clip).

**USING THE SPECIFIC TRANSITION**

1. Import that specific transition into your project.
2. At the end of the first clip, place the specific transition on the timeline.
3. Animate the motion of the transition: Start with the scale zoomed in on the "starting" video. Scale back to 100% while moving the clip to center the "ending" video. Scale up (zoom in) on the "ending" video.
4. When the "ending" video fills the screen, cut the specific transition.
5. Add the actual "ending" video to the timeline. Trim the left end of the clip to match the right end (last frames) of the clip in the specific transition.

I haven't tried this but in my mind it should work really well.  The video quality will be a bit lower during the transition, but it may not be noticeable - especially in lower-quality environments (like web video) or if the transition is brief (1-2 seconds).

Comment: Okay this is definitely a very complex way, but thank you very much anyways for the extensive answer :) I'll give it a try later, thanks!

Comment: @Dion There are a lot of steps when it's written out, but I THINK it's actually not too complicated. You make a template, then each time you want to use it you open the template, add 2 clips to it, resave it, and bring it into your project. But like I said I haven't DONE it, only ENVISIONED it, so it may be cumbersome or tricky or a lot of work. I hope not! And I hope it works for you, if no one offers a better solution!

Comment: @Dion I should have made a video demonstrating the idea. (But I'm at work right now!)

Comment: Nah you don't have to :) I don't have enough time atm. but I'll definitely try it as soon as possible. Thanks again!